# module context of execution

Tags: linux-kernel, network-programming, linux-device-driver

I work on module for ipsec in linux. Look at two different situations when code from my module will be executed.

Executing from process context: application generate some traffic to transmit via network, application should call some syscall to transfer data, then process switch to kernel space and packet go through network subsystem of linux, somewere here will be executed my module, and all finished after affording task to network card. All these steps performed from process context and in any moment scheduler can switch process from one to another. Is as follows fist case of using my module - from process context.

Executing from softirq context: when network card receive packet it generate hardware interrupt, which "prepare" appropriate softirq to run. And packet go through network subsystem of linux (including my module) until some application got it. These steps performed from softirq context and could be interrupted only by hardware interrupt, but not by scheduler work.

The question is: How can I programmatically determine in module, from which context module is executing? It can be some element of struct task_struct or some syscall or something else. I couldn't find it by myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is considered as a **bad practice** to make a function's control flow dependent from whether it is executed in interrupt context or not.

[Citation](https://lwn.net/Articles/274703/) from the Linux kernel developer (Andrew Morton):

> The consistent pattern we use in the kernel is that callers keep track of whether they are running in a schedulable context and, if necessary, they will inform callees about that. Callees don't work it out for themselves.

---

However, there are several functions(macros) defined in `linux/preempt.h` for detect current scheduling context: `in_atomic()`, `in_interrupt()`. But see [that LWN article](https://lwn.net/Articles/274695/) about their usage.

Comment: That is the thing I ask for, thank you. And explanation why I need such functionality in my driver: I write driver for CryptoApi based on аsynchronous mechanism. When driver got query it create a work using workqueue mechanism and return special code to the callees which mean "data processing in progress". Callees, of course, register callback function to go to when data encryption/decryption complete. The aforementioned work give the assignments to hardware for data processing. I need to know if process still exist in system before call callback function in case query come from process.

Comment: But if query came from softirq I am going to skip existence checking or not to produce work at all(don't use async mechanism of CryptoApi).